# How to open a cached file in a PWA with a native app?

Tags: android, ios, progressive-web-apps

I’m building a PWA that is going to used primarily on mobile. It has the ability to download maps (such as a KML file) and store them in the cache.
The goal however, is not to open this KML map within an in-browser map viewer when the user is offline. Rather, I want the native phone behavior to kick in where (in the case of iOS) it shows a list of compatible apps that the file can be opened in, and essentially hands over the file to the app that’s eventually selected.

I tried doing this. When I’m offline on the PWA and click a link to a map (which has been cached), nothing happens, no feedback whatsoever. But when I go online and again click on same the link, then it does what I want.

Why does this happen?

To summarise my question in a single sentence: What are the ways to go about opening a cached file ( that is not natively supported by Safari / Chrome ) in a PWA on mobile (**while offline**), yet have the browsers / OS offer to open them in other apps, or at the least offer to save them in like a Downloads folder ( or the Files app in the case of iOS), where it can then be read from later by a compatible app?

For reference, this is the prompt that shows up when I click on the map link on iOS but **only** when I'm online ( I want the equivalent behavior on Android too ):
[image]